# VBA Find formatted Cell

Tags: vba, excel, find

I'm trying to write a macro which will find, activate and cycle through any cells that have boarders all around the outside. It works when I use the find function, and I've recorded the following code, but when i run this code independently it hangs on the find portion for a while before returning a

> run time error '91'.

Any ideas why the recording isn't working the way the standard find format does?

```
    Sub FindBoarder()
'
' FindBoarder Macro
'

'
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Application.FindFormat.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=True).Activate
    Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: You will get that error if there are no cells found with the border specifications. I suggest you test if a cell has been found before activating anything.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out the problem, but in case you need help getting from there to a solution, here you go:

```
Dim ToActivate As Range

Set ToActivate = Cells.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=True)

If Not ToActivate Is Nothing Then
    ToActivate.Activate
Else
    Debug.Print "Not Found"
End If
```

The code above replaces your `Cells.Find` call. You'll want to do something similar with your `FindNext` call, though I'm really not sure what the relationship between these two calls is supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to repeat your script and surprisingly it works when there is any formatiing. The error occurs only when there aren't any cells with borders. The simple (but not right) way to get rid of it is to add in the beginning the line:

On Error Resume Next

And then this macro will work as 'tab' button)

Comment: Better might be to test if the cell has been found.

Comment: I conclude with Ron, using `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling is a very bad practice.